# Chain replace for the same character appearing multiple times

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Let's say I have a string like so

> Danny is ? James is ? Allen is ?

And I want to replace it to

> Danny is great James is wonderful Allen is magnificent

How can I use `replace` to do it?

I'm attempting to do something like

```
string.replace(/\?/g, 'great ').replace(/\?/g, 'wonderful ').replace(/\?/g, 'magnificent');
```

but I just get:

> Danny is great James is great Allen is great

If the case was something like:

> Danny is ? James is # Allen is $

```
string.replace(/\?/g, 'great ').replace(/\#/g, 'wonderful ').replace(/\$/g, 'magnificent');
```

It would work as expected, but since it's the same character it's not working.

Is there a neater way to achieve this than doing something like below?

```
string = string.replace(/\?/g, 'great ') 
string = string.replace(/\?/g, 'wonderful ')
string = string.replace(/\?/g, 'magnificent');
```

Comment: Why do you use the "global" flag, when you obviously don't want that "global" flag?

Comment: ^ The g or global flag replaces all instances of the regex, so you need to remove it to only replace the first found instance each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the replace function with a regular expression with the `/g` (meaning: "global") option, which means it will replace the '?' everywhere in the string.

To replace only one occurence of '?' at a time, just use a normal string to find, eg: `string.replace('?', 'great')`

So, your full example would be:

```js
string = string.replace('?', 'great ') 
string = string.replace('?', 'wonderful ')
string = string.replace('?', 'magnificent');
```